# C# Display compare timestamp to current month

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, timestamp, visual-studio-2015

So I am working on a voting system for a program I am working on and I am very new to C# so could use some help with this next part that I need. I am already grabbing the information I need from a json and it is displaying but now I need to get the check the unix timestamp and compare it to see if it is within a 24 hour period so it only displays results if it was listed within 24 hours of timestamp.

timestamp outputs the timestamp like this.

```
1439125612
```

I am not sure how I could use this timestamp to check if a person has voted within 24 hours. I only want them to be able to vote once every 24 hours and not cheat in anyway.

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var key = textBox6.Text;
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
   client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://exampleurl.com/api/?object=servers&element=votes&key=" + key + "&format=json"));
}

public class Vote
{
   public string date { get; set; }
   public int timestamp { get; set; }
   public string nickname { get; set; }
   public string steamid { get; set; }
   public string claimed { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string address { get; set; }
   public string port { get; set; }
   public string month { get; set; }
   public List<Vote> votes { get; set; }
}

void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
   foreach (var vote in rootObject.votes)
   {
      string vdate = vote.date;
      int vtimestamp = vote.timestamp;
      string timestamp = vtimestamp.ToString();
      string vnickname = vote.nickname;
      string vsteamid = vote.steamid;
      string vclimed = vote.claimed;
      textBox5.Text += "Date: " + vdate + "\r\n" 
                    + "Timestamp: " + timestamp + "\r\n" 
                    + "Nickname: " + vnickname + "\r\n" 
                    + "StreamID: " + vsteamid + "\r\n" 
                    + "Claimed: " + vclimed + "\r\n\r\n";
   }
}
```

EDIT: I edited the above to provide the correct information that I need. I am very tired and was not thinking clearly when I posted this. If anyone that answered already can revise their answer I will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual timestamp value in the json input? Json.NET can deserialize both ISO and old-style dates to DateTime values so you don't need to parse them.

Comment: timestamp is a Unix timestamp. I posted the incorrect information a minute  ago but revised my original question. I am trying to just grab the timestamp and only display values from the json based on if the person as voted within a 24 hour period.

Comment: Please post the *entire field content*. The de-facto standard is to use ISO-8601 dates, eg "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z". The integer format `/Date(1224043200000)/` was actually created by *Microsoft* in the early Ajax days when there was no convention. Json.Net can handle both cases. Even if the data is a raw integer, you can covert it to a DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now you should just parse Unix time. You can use this code to do it:

```
    public static DateTime ParseUnixDateTime(double unixTime)
    {
        var dt= new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dt= dt.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of splitting, it's better to just parse the string with `DateTime.Parse` with a US CultureInfo, omitting the timezone

Comment: If you parse this string with `en-US` cultureInfo - you will get error. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: I am sorry but I posted incorrect information in my original question, If you can please revise based on my edited question it would mean a lot.

Comment: Updated answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @ArtemKulikov oops, didn't notice that `th`. Without it (and the timezone) `DateTime.Parse` works

Comment: @ArtemKulikov Thank you helped a lot to understand what I needed.